# Editable repeating region in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, visual-web-part, content-editor-web-part

SharePoint Novice. Just as the image shows, I'm trying to create an editable repeating region in SharePoint and I have idea on how I can achieve that. Any suggestions or ideas on how I can get this done.

[image]

Comment: Define "editable". If you want to edit specific events, the easiest way is to just have two links under each event summary: "View Event | Edit"

Comment: User can't  edit. Editable in the sense that an admin user can always make changes to it.